# FxCop, Finding "If-Else" statements

Tags: c#, expression, fxcop, if-statement

I am using FxCop and coded  the following:

```
public override void VisitBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
{
    if (binaryExpression != null)
    {
        if (binaryExpression.Operand1 is MethodCall || binaryExpression.Operand2 is MethodCall)
        {
            Problem p = new Problem(GetResolution(null), binaryExpression);
            this.Problems.Add(p);
        }
    }
    base.VisitBinaryExpression(binaryExpression);
}
```

However, addition is also considered as a Binary Expression too. I am trying to block:

```
if ( myFunc()){
// cool code
}
```

And using this one instead:

```
bool b = myFunc();
if ( b){
// cool code
}
```

How can I find the if-else statements in FxCop and determine that the expression inside does not have any function calls?

Comment: Why would you want to block that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be looking for the Branch node type, then looking at the condition property.

A tool I found invaluable when working on creating rules is using The introspector found [here](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/index.html). It allows you to explore the code tree, displaying the note types and properties as you go. Create a program with an if statement in it, then expand until you see a , then take a look at the properties you should be checking for.

I would override the visit branch method, set a bool, then visit the 'condition nodes', then reset it afterwards. Then in your visitbinary you can only apply your rule if the bool is set (i.e. you're in the condition of a branch statement).

Comment: I did not implement it but I think that's the best solution.